# php Facebook like comment section

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am  trying to make a facebook like comment section, where the user can comment in specific post from the homepage. The problem is that If I try to comment in one post the comment gets looped into all the posts. Here the image :

[image]

Here's the php code

```
$get_posts = "SELECT * FROM  science_post WHERE                  user_id ORDER by 1 DESC LIMIT 5";
$run_posts = mysqli_query($conncate, $get_posts);

while ($row_posts = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)) {

    /** .. Some other code .. ***/

    $user_com = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
    $get_com = "select * from users where user_name='$user_com'";
    $run_com = mysqli_query($conn, $get_com);
    $row_com = mysqli_fetch_array($run_com);

    $user_com_id = $row_com['user_id'];
    $user_com_name = $row_com['user_name'];


    if (isset($_POST['submit_co'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['comment_co'])) {
            $comment = $_POST['comment_co'];


            $insert = "insert into science_comment (post_id,user_id,comment,comment_author,date) values ('$post_id','$user_com_id','$comment','$user_com_name', NOW())";
            $run = mysqli_query($conncate, $insert);
        } else {
            echo "<script> alert('Please enter a answer before submitting.')</script>";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments usually have parent IDs, from what I see, you seem to be selecting all comments by a specific user, and not by a specific message, therefore you'll see the same comment all over again.

Try something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM science_comment WHERE post_id = id ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is that, it is looping in the database table as well. I have 10 same comments with different comment id and post id in the science_comment table.